# DataTables Get All checkboxes for submit changes page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, datatables

[image][image]I am using asp.net datatables and this function call (below) to get all the checkboxes checked in a datatable.

```
$(oTable.fnGetNodes()).appendTo(this);
```

Its all working fine except for that I am using the value to download a file without leaving the page. I have a function in the code behind that correctly picks up the form fields and generates the file download.

The problem is that my page is messed up because you can see the appended content in the page.

I can't refresh/reload because the page is already refreshed from the postback of clicking the button, so any attempt to reload/refresh at that point is ignored.

This works fine if the button press submits to a different page, but submitting to the same page causes the display problem.

I don't want to redirect to another pages as the logic of my app there is no page to redirect to. It needs to stay on the same page

Top image show my table messed up with the `appendTo` content
Bottom image shows the paged correctly formatted before `appendTo`
Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax call behaves in asynchronous way, this might be your problem. You should make the ajax call synchronous as your function will wait until the response/download is completed by async:false parameter.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'URL',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'sample.txt',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        if(data!=null)
        {
          alert("Correct Data");
        }
        else
        {
          alert("Data is null");
         }
      }
     failure: function(response) {
          alert(response.d);
         }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me.

Comment: Your's Welcome. Hope it will help others too.

Comment: @wasim thanks loads for this, It wasn't the solution but in trying to make it  work it got me thinking and I came across as alternative that does work without ajax.

Comment: No problem. At least you get over the problem.